# how can I know sharing intent done?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-sharing

I want share something (plain text) via all sharing app in android.
and this is my code

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
String shareBody = toast;
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
```

but I want delivery message that my app detect sharing done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but I want delivery message that my app detect sharing done.

That is not supported by `ACTION_SEND` or `ACTION_SENDTO`. You do not find out if the user shares the content or how the user shares the content.

Comment: can i find this by other function?

Comment: @user3001854: No. You are delegating the sharing to a third-party application. You did not write the third-party application. The author(s) of the third-party application do not have to tell you anything.